# Find the general solution to the following recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Find the general solution to the following recurrence: $$nC_n=anC_{n-1}+bC_{n-1}$$
where a and b are constants.

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite the recurrence relation as 
$$\frac{C_n}{C_{n-1}}=\frac{an+b}{n}.$$
From this we can get
$$\prod_{n=1}^{n=m}\frac{C_n}{C_{n-1}}=\prod_{n=1}^{n=m}\frac{an+b}{n}.$$
The reduces to
$$C_m=C_0\prod_{n=1}^{n=m}\frac{an+b}{n}=\frac{C_0}{m!}\prod_{n=1}^{n=m}(an+b).$$

Comment: ${}=C_0a^m\binom{m+\frac{b}{a}}{m}$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from Anurag's answer, we could go one step further and show that $$C_m=C_0\prod_{n=1}^{n=m}\frac{an+b}{n}=\frac{C_0}{m!}\prod_{n=1}^{n=m}(an+b)=\frac{C_0}{m!}\frac{a^m \Gamma \left(\frac{b}{a}+m+1\right)}{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{b}{a}+1\right)}$$ which would simplify a lot if $a$ is a divisor of $b$, whatever $a$ could be. Suppose that $b=n a$, $n$ being an integer, then for that case $$C_m=C_0~ a^m \frac{(m+n)!}{m!~~n!}$$